# Figure next to text in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats

I can't get my code to do what I want. I'm working in `beamer` and I want to position my figure on the left side of the frame and the text next to it, but I would like to work with alineas in my text.
Here's my latest attempt:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Madrid}   
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}  
\usepackage{curvedarrows}  
\usepackage{cutwin}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}  
\def\leq{\leqslant}  
\def\geq{\geqslant}   

\title{De regel van Horner: \\ Een vleugje geschiedenis}  
\date{}  

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}  

\begin{frame}[plain]  
  \titlepage  
\end{frame}  

\begin{frame}  
       \begin{tabular}{cl}  
           \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{horner} & bla bla 

    *here I want to start a new alinea, so in my second column* bla bla  
         \end{tabular}  
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is by far no MWE ;-) Please remove the `curvedarrows` etc. packages. from this example

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use a nested `tabular` or `tabularx` environment, in order to provide a better alignment, in combination with a `\parbox` command, the width of the latter has to be adapted to fit into the frame better.

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Madrid}   
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}  
%\usepackage{curvedarrows}  
%\usepackage{cutwin}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
%\usepackage[3D]{movie15}  
\def\leq{\leqslant} % eleganter \leq-symbool  
\def\geq{\geqslant} % eleganter \geq-symbool  

\title{De regel van Horner: \\ Een vleugje geschiedenis}  
\date{}  
\subject{Slides voor het vak Vakdidactiek wiskunde} % zichtbaar in het "Properties"   venster van de PDF-viewer  
\keywords{LaTeX, beamer, presentaties} % idem  

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}  

\begin{frame}[plain]  
  \titlepage  
\end{frame}  

\begin{frame}  
       \begin{tabular}{cl}  
         \begin{tabular}{c}
           \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{horner}
           \end{tabular}
           & \begin{tabular}{l}
             \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{%  change the parbox width as appropiate
             \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits wiskundige. 

    Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op 14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath waar hij een school stichtte.  
    }
         \end{tabular}  \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(Since I did not have the **horner** image at hand, I used one of Erwin Schrödinger instead ;-))

[image]

Comment: I was thinking Mr. Horner bore a striking resemblance to a famous quantum physicist ;^)

Answer (score 72):

You can use `columns` provided by `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\leq{\leqslant} % eleganter \leq-symbool
\def\geq{\geqslant} % eleganter \geq-symbool

\title{De regel van Horner: \\ Een vleugje geschiedenis}
\date{}
\subject{Slides voor het vak Vakdidactiek wiskunde} % zichtbaar in het "Properties"   venster van de PDF-viewer
\keywords{LaTeX, beamer, presentaties} % idem

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
       \begin{columns}
          \column{0.38\linewidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{example-image}
           \column{0.58\linewidth}
              \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits
                wiskundige. Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op
                14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath
                 waar hij een school stichtte.
         \end{columns} 
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me terrible vertical alignment unless I wrap the content of both columns in `\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}...\end{minipage}`.

Comment: Elegant, thank you.

Answer (score 16):

A different approach with `minipage`s (much simpler than with `tabular`):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % remove this line in your document
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
%\usepackage{curvedarrows}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\def\leq{\leqslant} % eleganter \leq-symbool
\def\geq{\geqslant} % eleganter \geq-symbool

\title{De regel van Horner: \ Een vleugje geschiedenis}
\date{}
\subject{Slides voor het vak Vakdidactiek wiskunde} % zichtbaar in het "Properties" venster van de PDF-viewer
\keywords{LaTeX, beamer, presentaties} % idem

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{horner}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits wiskundige.
Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op 14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath waar hij een school stichtte.
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Slightly tricky to work with especially when trimming the image on the side (using the respective parameter for `\includegraphics`) but the result is quite nice. In my case I actually used a beamer itemized bullet point list on the right with pauses and the effect is pretty pro looking (subjective opinion here :D). This is also a better way then using a table if on the text side you actually have a table. I really don't like nested tables.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution with the `adjustbox` package.

Load these two packages

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
```

and use fixed widths for your columns

```
\begin{tabular}{m{3.5cm}m{7cm}}
```

Also, add the option `valign=C` to `\includegraphics`

```
\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm,valign=C]{horner}
```

MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % remove this line in your document
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
%\usepackage{curvedarrows}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\def\leq{\leqslant} % eleganter \leq-symbool
\def\geq{\geqslant} % eleganter \geq-symbool

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\title{De regel van Horner: \ Een vleugje geschiedenis}
\date{}
\subject{Slides voor het vak Vakdidactiek wiskunde} % zichtbaar in het "Properties" venster van de PDF-viewer
\keywords{LaTeX, beamer, presentaties} % idem

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{m{3.5cm}m{7cm}}
\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm,valign=C]{horner} & \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits wiskundige.
Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op 14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath waar hij een school stichtte.
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution using `sidebyside` boxes (from `tcolorbox`).

With a `sidebyside` box, we can use options like `{lefthand|righthand} width` or `{lefthand|righthand} ratio` to easily change proportions between both sides. It's also possible to define vertical alignments between both side contents and horizontal alignments inside each box.

And use all other coloring and drawing tools provided by `tcolorbox`.

following code shows the default behaviour and a `blanker` environment where `sidebyside` box is only used for space distribution, nothing is drawn behind contents.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mysidebyside}[1][]{
    notitle, sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=center seam,
    halign=center,
    lefthand width=.3\textwidth,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{mysidebyside}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
    \tcblower
    \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits
                wiskundige. Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op
                14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath
                 waar hij een school stichtte.
\end{mysidebyside} 

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\begin{mysidebyside}[blanker, lefthand width=.6\linewidth]
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
    \tcblower
    \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits
                wiskundige. Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op
                14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath
                 waar hij een school stichtte.
\end{mysidebyside} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]