# How to put Figure with caption next to text in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, diagrams, presentations

Reading a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165475/figure-next-to-text-in-beamer), I encountered a problem: How do I place a picture with a caption in beamer?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Madrid}   
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}  
%\usepackage{curvedarrows}  
%\usepackage{cutwin}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
%\usepackage[3D]{movie15}  
\def\leq{\leqslant} % eleganter \leq-symbool  
\def\geq{\geqslant} % eleganter \geq-symbool  

\title{De regel van Horner: \\ Een vleugje geschiedenis}  
\date{}  
\subject{Slides voor het vak Vakdidactiek wiskunde} % zichtbaar in het "Properties"   venster van de PDF-viewer  
\keywords{LaTeX, beamer, presentaties} % idem  

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}  

\begin{frame}[plain]  
  \titlepage  
\end{frame}  

\begin{frame}  
       \begin{tabular}{cl}  
         \begin{tabular}{c}
           \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{horner}
           \caption[Caption string]{Figure caption}
           \end{tabular}
           & \begin{tabular}{l}
             \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{%  change the parbox width as appropiate
             \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits wiskundige. 

    Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op 14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath waar hij een school stichtte.  
    }
         \end{tabular}  \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome on tex.stackexchange.com! Please provide a Minimal Working Example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason to use any tabulars here when `beamer` has a columns concept (I uses a black blob instead of an image)

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Madrid}   
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}  

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}  
       \begin{columns}
         \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
           \begin{figure}
             % \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{horner}
             \rule{3.5cm}{5cm}
             \caption[Caption string]{Figure caption}
           \end{figure}
         \end{column}
         \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
           \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven
           in 1837) was een Brits wiskundige.
               
           Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij
           reeds op 14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding
           volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath waar hij een school
           stichtte.  
       \end{column}
     \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what about tabular evironment?

Comment: @EugenS why do you need it?